# Element is not removed from array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to delete an actor from actors `array` which is inside movie `object`.
Firstly, I map actors to display actors one by one and adding a remove action to button.
Whole ActorsList component

```
const PostList = ({ movie, removeActorFromMovie }, props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Actors in film </h3>
      {movie.actors.map((actor, i) => (
        <div key={actor}>
          {actor}
          <button onClick={() => removeActorFromMovie(actor)}>Usuń</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    movie: state.movies.find((movie) => movie.id === props.match.params.id),
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  removeActorFromMovie,
};
export default withRouter(
  connect

(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList)
);
```

Action:

```
export const removeActorFromMovie = (payload) => ({
  type: "MOVIE_ACTOR_DELETE",
  payload,
});
```

Reducer:

```
 case "MOVIE_ACTOR_DELETE":
      return [...state.filter((el) => el !== action.payload)];
```

Although, the payload wokrs great and returns the array item. It does not remove it from an array.
My movies array with movie under index 0:

```
movies: Array(1)
 0:
  actors: (2) ['Robert XYZ', 'Jake XYZ']
  director: "Quentino TARANTINO, TARANTINO"
  id: "352cc51e-87c4-46ec-84a0-9f308ec1a71a"
  productionYear: "123"
  title: "Titanic"
```

and payload:

```
payload: "Robert XYZ"
type: "MOVIE_ACTOR_DELETE"
```

and as I said, this doest not remove the actor from actors array which is under index 0 in movies array

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I'm supposing your state is something like this:

```
state: {
  movies: [...]
}
```

If you want to remove an actor from a movie you should also pass the payload a movie to remove the actor from.

`removeActorFromMovie(actor, movie)`
then in the reducer:

```
const { movie, actor } = action.payload;
const nextMovie = {
  ...movie,
  actors: movie.actors.filter((a) => a !== actor)
};
const movieIndex = state.movies.findIndex((m) => m.id === movie.id);
return {
    ...state,
    movies: [
      ...state.movies.slice(0, movieIndex),
      nextMovie,
      ...state.movies.slice(movieIndex + 1)
    ]
};
```

---

OLD ANSWER (If you instead want to remove a movie):

If you want to remove a movie based on its actors you filter function will not work. You are trying to remove an item whose value is "Robert XYZ" but the element passed to you filter function is a movie.

if the state is like this:

```
movies: [
  {
  actors: ['Robert XYZ', 'Jake XYZ']
  director: "Quentino TARANTINO, TARANTINO"
  id: "352cc51e-87c4-46ec-84a0-9f308ec1a71a"
  productionYear: "123"
  title: "Titanic"
  }
]
```

then you can do:

```
const nextItems = state.filter(movie => !movie.actors.includes(action.payload))
return nextItems;
```

There is no need to create a new copy of the filtered array with the spread operator because `filter` return a new copy of the original array.

Comment: Im not trying to remove a movie based on actor. Im trying to remove a actor from movie.

Comment: As you said, im trying to remove an item "Robert XYZ" in this case. Althoug the code i did, does not work and it does not remove actor from actors array

Comment: I've updated the response with code to remove an actor from a movie.

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  16 |         ...state,
  17 |         movies: state.movies.slice(state.slice(0, movieIndex), nextMovie, state.slice(movieIndex + 1) 
> 18 |       }
     |       ^
  19 |
  20 |       
  21 |     case "MOVIE_ACTOR_ADD":

Comment: it gives me an eslint error now, i thougt about adding a  " ) ". But when i add ) , then it says that 'payload' is not defined.   const movie = payload.movie; <- here

Comment: Sorry it should be action.payload.movie;

Comment: Updated and formatted the code

Comment: My state is acctually like this: const movieReducer = (state = [], action)

Comment: this is the reducer. How did you define state (initial state) ? as an array or as an object containing the movie object ?

Comment: According to the  firefox console. Movies is an array of objects. This is my Movie Form component: https://pastebin.com/sCTtFdyP. My case of "MOVIE_ADD"      return [...state, action.payload];.

Comment: And btw. this still don't work. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'actors')

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h81CbaGy

Comment: > TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'actors')
This means that movie is undefined. Are you passing it to the payload ?